# Oracle PL/SQL User input error "Bind variable not declared"

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
accept x char prompt 'Please enter something: '
declare 
  a varchar2(50);
begin
  a := '&x';
  Select MIN(lowest_elevation) as lowest , Max(highest_elevation)as highest FROM countries where country_name = :a;
end;
```

i am taking input from a user then passing it into a where clause. and i cant seem to find any solutions online. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` is a PL/SQL local variable, not a SQL bind variable, so it should not have the colon when you refer to it:

```
where country_name = a;
```

For it to be a bind variable it would need to be defined by the client/application/IDE; in SQL Developer, for instance:

```
accept x char prompt 'Please enter something: '
variable a varchar2(50);

begin
  :a := '&x';
  Select MIN(lowest_elevation) as lowest , Max(highest_elevation)as highest
  FROM countries
  where country_name = :a;
end;
```

Note that now there is no `declare` section, as you are no longer declaring `a` as a PL/SQL variable - it's a client variable. To assign the substitution variable `&x` to it it then needs the colon, `:a := '&x';`, because it's a bind variable there too.

I'm not saying that's what you should do; just showing the difference.

You can also skip the `a` variable completely, of course:

```
accept x char prompt 'Please enter something: '

begin
  Select MIN(lowest_elevation) as lowest , Max(highest_elevation)as highest
  FROM countries
  where country_name = '&x';
end;
```

Incidentally, you have to select *into* something, so your code still won't work as it's currently written.

Comment: thanks bro it works. i was confused with other language. i found a solution to the 
into error